# Google apps script "Those columns are out of bounds" error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that tries to delete columns that is not needed by the user. When i run the script the first time, it gives the "Those columns are out of bounds" error but when i try to run it again, it suddenly runs without any errors.

First loop = loops through the column headers in the table

Second loop = loops through the array that contains column headers that the user WANTS to remain

Here is the code for reference:

```
//loop through the included columns + loop through the continent columns
dummyLR = dummyWS.getLastRow();
continentWS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(continentName);
continentLC = continentWS.getLastColumn();
var colArr = dummyWS.getRange('A1:A' + dummyLR).getValues();

continentWS.activate();

for(var j = continentLC; j >= 1; j--){

    for(var i = 0; i < colArr.length; i++){

        if(continentWS.getRange(1, j).getValue() == colArr[i]){
            deleteScore = 1;
        }

    }

    Logger.log(j);
    if(deleteScore != 1){
        continentWS.deleteColumn(j);
    }
    deleteScore = 0;

}
```

The error starts showing up on the line:

```
continentWS.deleteColumn(j);
```

I tried counting the existing columns and comparing it to the continentLC variable and they are matched so i don't know why it returns an out of bounds error.

Comment: When you run the function in debug mode, what do you notice about the values of your loop variables, and the columns on each sheet?

Comment: I see at least 1 error in the first "if" condition: the left part is **a single value**, but the right one is **an array**...

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин the right one has an array index so it will only return 1 value. I checked it with Logger.log and it returns 1 value per loop.

Comment: @Cooper continentName is a spreadsheet name. There's a sheet where the user interacts with. The user will choose where to extract the data. When i log it, it always return the same value. With regards to dummyWS, it was defined before the block of code i pasted here so it's all good.

Comment: @tehhowch when i debug it, it debugs at the continentWS.deleteColumn(j); line

Comment: @bins yes, and in the lower portion of the screen, where the current variables are detailed, what are the values of interest? (E.g. `j`, and how many columns are on `continentWS`)

Comment: @tehhowch j = 29 while continentLC = 29 too. The table goes from A to AC so it's accurate.

Comment: @tehhowch i tried the catching error + column # then placing it in a cell as text. I got 'Exception: Those columns are out of bounds. 29' So the error starts immediately at column 29 which is weird since it exists.

Comment: @bins , when you write `colArr[i]`, you take an element of one dimension and get **an array**, because colArr is 2-dimensional